# Find bipartial subgraph such that number of edges is maximum and sum of edge lengths is maximum

Tags: algorithms, graphs, bipartite-graph

Let there be graph $G = (V, E)$. $G$ has neither loops nor parallel arcs.

$V = A \cup B, \, A \neq \emptyset, \, B \neq \emptyset, A \cap B = \emptyset$

For simplicity's sake, let's consider $G$ is directed.

$\forall \ e \in E \ \, e.tail \in A, \, e.head \in B, \, e.length \in (\mathbb{Z} \cap [1, 100]) \cup -\infty \\
\forall \ a \in A, \, b \in B \ \ \exists! \ e \in E: e = (a, b)$

**The goal is** to develop an algorithm that finds a bipartite subgraph $G' = (V', \, E')$ such that:

1) $|\,E'\;|$ **is maximum**;
2) Under restriction 1), $\sum \limits_{e' \in E'} e'.length$ **is maximum possible**.

For example, let graph $G$ be defined as following:[image]

There are two subgraphs that satisfy 1):
[image]

and

[image]

However, sum of the edge lengths of the second subgraph is greater than sum of the edge lengths of the first subgraph so the second subgraph is the correct answer.

The algorithm should run in polynomial time.

Comment: Are you really looking for a bipartite graph with those restrictions or a matching (each vertex is incident to at most one chosen edge)? Because if you are looking for a bipartite subgraph of maximal size then trivially there is only the full bipartite graph you start with. Otherwise, this is a maximum weight matching problem, which you can easily lookup.

Comment: Do you have the restriction that each node must have degree 1? Otherwise why not include every edge that has `w > 0`

Answer (score 0):

The way to make $|E'|$ be maximum is to take all the edges, i.e., set $E'=E$.  Since your graph is already bipartite, this subgraph will be as well.  Then criterion 2 is irrelevant, as there is only one way to achieve the maximum for criterion 1.